# How to add span in li of ActiveAdmin menu, in Rails 5?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

How we can add a span in li tag of menu in ActiveAdmin? Here is the model content of the Menu Item:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }, html_options: { class: "dashboard" }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    div class: "blank_slate_container", id: "dashboard_default_message" do
      span class: "blank_slate" do
        span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
        small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
      end
    end
  end # content
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu items are surrounded by a link tag like so:

```
<li class="current" id="dashboard"><a href="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
```

What you can try, but am not sure if this is what you need, is:

```
menu priority: 1, label: proc{ "<span id='39740772'>#{I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard")}</span>".html_safe }
```

That will result in this html. It does put a  tag inside the **li** but maybe too deep. If you need your **span** around the **a** this approach won't work.

```
<li class="current" id="dashboard"><a href="/admin/dashboard"><span id='39740772'>Dashboard</span></a></li>
```